# Concurrency in Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, concurrency

I have a chat application in google app engine. I am facing the concurrency issues. 
When the chat starts from one end, that chat will broadcast to all available agents in the account. When 1 guy responds that guy will take ownership and remove all the remaining guys in that session.

Here i am facing problem with concurrent requests from more than 1 agent response at the same time. At this point each request takes out the remaining agents in the session and no body is there in the session.

I thought this solves with code synchronization. But with multiple instances doesn't work this logic. Since the code is in different servers.

Is there a way to acheive this make synchronize using datastore/memcache.

Please suggest on this.

Thanks in advance.

Govind.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using CAS with  memcache, alternately you can use transactions in the datastore and plan control entities with known keys.  I don't use java so can't whip up an example , and I can only find api docs for java on cas

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.CasValues

but the writeup in python would still explain what is going on .

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_Using_compare_and_set_in_Python

Comment: This is a pretty good idea - there's a little bit of info here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/#Java_Safely_handling_concurrent_memcache_updates - the only thing to keep in mind is memcache has the contract that it is to be considered volatile, and can be flushed at any point. That means you need to be able to represent the same logic in the datastore (or somewhere else) if it needs to be reconstituted.

Comment: Yep transitory nature of memcache can be a problem, but in this situation I doubt it as the OP is trying to resolve a near simultaneous set of requests to a first in gets the the session.  Once the session has been allocated that should if necessary be represented in the datastore.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this using transactions. But some reason it wont work out to me. I dont know the reason. But with Memcache increment/decrement solves the problem. These methods are atomic. This pretty simple and optimistic.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/wtESRwKCF5U

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using Transactions. But some reason it wont work out to me. I dont know the reason. But with Memcache increment/decrement we can solve the problem. These methods are atomic. This is simple and optimistic.

Please go through this group

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/wtESRwKCF5U

Thanks for your updates.

Govind.